# Xpath syntax to convert the XML into string

Tags: xpath

I need to calculate the number of characters of a full XML:

```
<data>
<a>123</a>
<b>456</b>
</data>
```

What would be the Xpath syntax to first convert that into a string so that I can use `string-length()` to get the number of characters?

Comment: Do you mean something like `string-length(normalize-space(string(/)))`  ?

Comment: I want to count all characters in this string ```<data><a>123</a><b>456</b></data>```. ```normalize-space``` removes the whitespaces in the texts of the nodes.

Comment: Basically, I want to convert that entire XML document into a string. so that I can do ```string-length('<data>.....</data>')```

Comment: So what is the length you are expecting back for this example ?

Comment: 37 characters, including 3 new line characters(i.e. ```\n```)

Comment: With XPath questions, please always state what version of XPath you are able to use.

Comment: I am limited by version 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 3.1 you can do

```
serialize(., map{'omit-xml-declaration':true()})
=> string-length()
```

Note that the resulting XML from `serialize()` may differ in minor respects from what you started with.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your software is parsing that XML and producing an instance of the XML Data Model, and your XPath is operating over that XDM instance.

You should be aware that the conversion from an XML text file to an XDM instance does lose some information, and XML files which are textually different can produce indistinguishable XDM instances.

A couple of examples: [element start tags can contain extra white space](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-starttags) which will be irrelevant to the XML parser, and characters can be encoded either directly or by using so-called ["character references"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-references) (e.g. `1` is the same as `&#x31;`) meaning that the following two documents will be indistinguishable by your XPath:

```xml
<data>
<a>123</a>
<b>456</b>
</data>
```

```xml
<data >
<a    >&#x31;23</a>
<b  >456</b>
</data>
```

This means that an XPath 1.0 query can't know exactly how many characters were present in the source document before it was parsed.

Using later versions of XPath, it'd be possible to read the XML source document as unparsed text, and simply measure the number of characters using the `string-length` function.